# Calling dynamic components in Vue JS with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-blade

I'm trying to build an application on `Laravel 5.4` and `Vue JS 2.0` I'm having a set of `components` which are being used in specific page only, right now I'm defining the components globally and using the components tag in blade file, as I said lot components are of no use, so my mix file is getting bigger and I think this might slow down my page rendering. I'm looking for a solution where I can call components dynamically in blade file. Following is my `app.js` file:

```
Vue.component('NavBar', require('./components/NavBar.vue'));
Vue.component('HomeBanner', require('./components/HomeBanner.vue'));
Vue.component('PageFooter', require('./components/Footer.vue'));
Vue.component('Categories', require('./components/Categories.vue'));
Vue.component('SubCategory', require('./components/SubCategory.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I've a `master blade` file which have following HTML codes:

```
<div id="app">
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    @yield('content')
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <page-footer></page-footer>
</div>

<!-- Core Scripts for Vue Components -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and suppose in `index.blade.php` I've

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'HomePage')

@section('content')
    <home-banner></home-banner>
@endsection
```

and in `categories` page I'm having:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Select your category')

@section('content')
    <categories></categories>
@endsection
```

any suggestion how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create a new file, say, partial.js at the same level of your app.js with this:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('categories', require('./components/Categories.vue'));
new Vue({
    el: '#testing'
});
```

Add the partial.js to the elixir webpack in gulpfile.js. Should look like this:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js')
       .webpack('partial.js');
});
```

Then in the blade file you want to have this enclose the 'category' tag between a div with id='testing'

After that, import the partials.js script like this:

```
<script src="/js/partials.js"></script>
```

I believe the importing here has to be done AFTER using the category component.

Your categories page should end up like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Select your category')

@section('content')
    <div id='testing'>
        <categories></categories>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/partials.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Try it out and let me know, that's how I solved a similar problem in the past. Cheers!